# Where did the meat of Celestial framework go?

Tags: iphone

I'm looking for the meat of the Celestial binary, which previously (iPhoneOS < 3.1) existed in
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework

That directory contains now (iPhoneOS >= 3.1) only plist-files...

Has the meat of that Celestial binary been merged into another binary/framework? (And yes, I know that this is not part of the official SDK...)

Thanks in advance!
 /Steve

Comment: Ok, found this finally out. All libraries have been merged into a cache found underneath: /System/Library/Caches
Read http://blog.howett.net/?p=75 for info how to extract the libraries which then may be dumped using otool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still there..

I can share it if you accidentally deleted it or you still haven't found it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not accidentally delete it... Just wanted to look something up. Found out how to obtain it though as can been seen in my comment above.